# Modify Context menus

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code to add a menu item on the Word 2013 right click menu:

```
    Sub CreateMenuItem()
        Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
        With CommandBars("Text")
            Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            With MenuButton
                .Caption = ChrW(&H2714) '"Correct"
                .Style = msoButtonCaption
                .OnAction = "InsertMark"
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

The issue is that the new menu item is not displayed when I right click on a Text box or a table.

How do I remove a menu item that is not used by me, for example "Translate"

Please Assist
Thinus

Answer (score 0):

Word provides a completely different `CommandBar` object for each context-sensitive menu, rather than dynamically changing the contents of a single menu. That means you need to make the change for each context in which your command should appear.

You can generate a list of CommandBars by looping the collection and writing the various properties out (for example, in a new document). Then you have to inspect that list, pick out the likely candidates, run your code then see if you guessed correctly.

You want to be *very careful* where these changes are SAVED in Word. If you don't specify it specifically, Word could save the change in one place and delete it (assuming you "undo" your changes) in a different one. This can really muck up the Word configuration and make users extremely unhappy. So *always* use `Application.CustomizationContext` at the beginning of code that changes the `CommandBars`. The `CustomizationContext` can be any `Document` or `Template` object.

**NOTE**: The `CommandBars` object is actually deprecated as of Word 2010. From Word 2013 onwards the context menus should be customized using Ribbon XML. Just saying... It's possible that in a future version your code will no longer work.