# VBA programming for a mouse click event.

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is a straightforward question. I have a small VBA code that changes curly quotes to straight line quotes. I would like this code to be available after selecting an area with a mouse and then performing some type of click event.

For instance I Would want to highlight the sentence

> “American  Academy of Orthopaedic Surgeons.....”

and then after highlighting perform some type of click event in order to run the VBA code.

Comment: Add a custom button to the ribbon and assign your macro to it? [Manually](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-3c610b47-6f0f-4179-83d3-68a254a80ea6#__toc266259183) or [programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705(v=office.14).aspx)?

Comment: Code like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36445064/3397613) allows you to add your own item in the context menu (right-click menu) that will call a macro of your choosing).